# / being added before query string in URI

Tags: django, reactjs, django-rest-framework, axios

My URI and query string has the below format, and as you can see this morning it was working.

```
[api-deployment-dev-6b4f758c54-8rwxt api] [10/Aug/2020 10:44:22] "GET /survey/129/results/advanced_query?startingPage=12&dataView=By%20Position HTTP/1.1" 200 2
```

For some reason it quit working despite these being the only two files I've changed today and I haven't been able to get it working again. I now keep getting the following:

```
[api-deployment-dev-7cf59c8b8-b6p4k api] Bad Request: /api/survey/129/results/advanced_query/
[api-deployment-dev-7cf59c8b8-b6p4k api] [10/Aug/2020 12:38:54] "GET /survey/129/results/advanced_query/?startingPage=12&dataView=By%20Position HTTP/1.1" 400 0
```

It seems like `react`, or `axios`, or something else is adding the `/` before the query string. Why, I'm not sure because it wasn't doing it this morning.

How do I prevent this from happening?

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import {
  Button,
  InputGroup,
  InputGroupText,
  InputGroupAddon,
  Input,
} from "reactstrap";

import axios from "axios";

const AdvancedQuerySurveyDataView = ({ surveyDataView }) => {
  const [startingPage, setStartingPage] = useState(null);
  const [option, setOption] = useState();

  const handleClick = async () => {
    const result = await axios({
      url: `/api/survey/${sessionStorage.getItem(
        "survey_id"
      )}/results/advanced_query?startingPage=${startingPage}&dataView=${option}`,
      method: "get",
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
        Authorization: "Bearer " + sessionStorage.getItem("token"),
      },
    });
  };

  return (
    <div className="results-position-list">
      <h5>
        <b>Select Survey Data View to Print</b>
      </h5>
      <select
        onChange={(e) => setOption(e.currentTarget.value)}
        id="position-list"
        className="form-control"
      >
        <option></option>
        {surveyDataView.map(({ surveydataview, min }) => (
          <option key={min} value={surveydataview}>
            {surveydataview}
          </option>
        ))}
      </select>
      <InputGroup>
        <InputGroupAddon addonType="prepend">
          <InputGroupText className="input-text">
            Enter Starting Page Number
          </InputGroupText>
        </InputGroupAddon>
        <Input
          type="number"
          min={0}
          max={100}
          step="1"
          onChange={(event) => setStartingPage(event.target.value)}
        />
        <InputGroupAddon addonType="append">
          <Button
            onClick={handleClick}
            disabled={
              startingPage > 0 && option !== undefined && option !== ""
                ? false
                : true
            }
          >
            Generate Section
          </Button>
        </InputGroupAddon>
      </InputGroup>
    </div>
  );
};

export default AdvancedQuerySurveyDataView;
```

```
from django.urls import path

from .views import (
    GeneratePDFView
)

app_name = 'Results'

urlpatterns = [
    path('results/advanced_query',
         GeneratePDFView.as_view(), name='generate_pdf')
]
```

Comment: React does not make ajax requests, its just a UI library. The issue is more likely to be related to `axios` or the browser, server, or some other source, but very very unlikely to be caused by react.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, this got it working again using `params` in the `axios`:

```
  const handleClick = async () => {
    const result = await axios({
      url: `/api/survey/${sessionStorage.getItem("survey_id")}/results/advanced_query`,
      method: "get",
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
        Authorization: "Bearer " + sessionStorage.getItem("token"),
      },
      params: {
        startingPage: startingPage,
        dataView: option
      }
    });
  };
```

Just incredibly strange it was working without it previously.